# Can a paper get rejected after acceptance due to incorporation of reviewer comments

Tags: journals, proofreading

Recently I got a paper accepted in a high impact journal. The acceptance letter came to me with a few reviewer comments, and it was recommended in the letter to take care of those comments. I submitted the final version with incorporating those revisions in the paper and due to one particular comment, I had to change a paragraph almost entirely.

But now after the proofreading, the journal says only formatting changes can be made, and other changes need further approval from Editor in Chief. Can this anyway jeopardize the paper and result in its rejection? Also, is there any way to communicate with the journal to settle this issue?

Comment: I am confused. They paper has been accepted right? If it is in the proofreading part, then this means that the final version has been accepted by the editor, and only typos are to be corrected.  Do you want to change anything more at this stage?

Comment: The paper has been accepted and with the acceptance letter some comments from the reviewers also came, which I incorporated in the paper. The comments were mostly trivial, like grammar and typos, but for one or two comments, we had to change the writing of a paragraph, though the writing actually meant the same thing as before but it in a clearer and crisper way. After this, the final files were submitted, which was before the proofreading stage. The got the no change mail from the journal after the proofreading stage.

Comment: Do you plan to do changes on your manuscript at this proof reading state? You made the necessary corrections and the meaning of the mail is that the paper is basically under production and you cannot change its content (modulo E-i-C approval).

Comment: @PsySp, I think I did not fully clarify my statement. The journal asked me to submit a final version of the paper after the acceptance letter came. I forgot to mention that the paper went through an earlier round of review and I submitted a review version after incorporating those reviews. It then got accepted and the reviewers asked for some minor final reviews, out of which one or two made me rewrite a paragraph. I then submitted that as the final version as the journal asked.

Comment: It is only after this submission that the proofreading stage began, so I had already incorporated all the reviews before proof reading stage even began. The proof that came to me was done on the final version that I submitted, i.e. the version that took care of the final comments of the reviewers. So basically I want to say that I made the changes **before** the proofreading stage and after the the acceptance, and note that the **changes were not made arbitrarily by me**, they were **as per the final comments of the reviewers**, and the **recommendation of the EiC**.

Comment: Does the statement of the journal that "only formatting changes can be made, and other changes need further approval from Editor in Chief" refer to the changes that you already did before submitting the final version, or to any (potential) additional changes that you might want to do now, after receiving the proofs?

Comment: It sound like you manuscript was "accepted with minor revisions". This usually means that the editor checks whether you did these revisions after resubmission. Proofreading is then the next step. Do you have a more senior coauthor who can provide some guidance to you?

Comment: @Uwe, it refers to the changes that I made before submitting the final version, after the acceptance.

Comment: @Roland, the journal had already sent me the proof with the version that I submitted, however, later the Editor assistant sent me a mail saying that revisions cannot be done once a paper is accepted, however, in the acceptance letter it said that revisions should be considered. Yes, I have a senior coauthor, he advised me to write to the Editor in Chief explaining the situation. I have written, but it has been two weeks but they have been unresponsive. I have asked about the status several times, but did not get any response.

Comment: I'd ask the "Editor assistant" for guidance on how to proceed. I suspect that either you have misunderstood something or there was a mistake by the editorial office. Maybe the editor clicked something wrong in the submission management system.

Comment: @Roland, the Editor Assistant said that I can either send the accepted version to the publication team, or if I want to retain the final version with the revisions, I have to write a justification that has to be sent to the EiC, only the EiC can approve such matter. I have done that and sent them, but it has been two weeks, and I have asked them for status update but got no response, which is why I am now getting scared.

Comment: Though the paper is accepted, and even the publication team is ready as soon as they get the final version, this matter is withholding the publication process.  is it anyway possible that the paper can get rejected at this stage?

Comment: They spent a lot of effort already. It's very unlikely that they would reject now. Don't be scared. Of course, this hiccup is slowing down the proceedings ... The EiC might simply be traveling or sick or otherwise not available.

Comment: @Roland, thanks for showing some hope. I also think that probably it might be some unintentional delay slowing things down, but since this is going to be my first major publication, I got nervous.

Answer (score 4):

What you've described sounds like a 'conditional acceptance', but I'm confused how you got to the proof stage without addressing the comments suggested. How did that happen? Also, no, do not make major changes during the proof stage.

Comment: I actually submitted the final version with the revisions, I have made an edit, please see.

Comment: Also, the acceptance letter said specifically that the paper was accepted.

Comment: I made the changes after the acceptance letter came, and introduced the revisions in the final version that I submitted. Can that create a problem? Also, I did not make any major change during the proof, just some changes in the references, and biographies etc.

Comment: What "further changes can only be made with approval of the Editor-in-Chief" usually means is changes ***after*** you submit your revised version that addresses the comments of the referees.

Answer (score 4):

Reviewers sometimes have further complaints, even when the editor has decided to accept a paper.  If the editor issues an acceptance, you should not attempt to respond to the remaining reviewer comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask the journal what you should do. And then do it.

If you represent everything as it happened, then the journal gave you the wrong instructions. Maybe you misunderstood. It does not matter.

Presumably, you are dealing with a person at the journal who is in charge of typesetting and no longer with an Associate Editor. Explain to them that you were trying to follow the instructions in the acceptance letter, but in case you misunderstood them, offer to submit the version of the paper you submitted before acceptance, with the small corrections that needed to be made, but without the alterations to that paragraph. You might include the acceptance letter. As long as you are willing to cooperate with them, your article will get published.